# Constrained Randomization of data frame in R

Tags: r, random

I have a data frame like this :

```
 Tem    Time
 10a      1
 10a      2
 10a      3 
 10a      4 
 20a      1
 20a      2
 20a      3
 20a      4 
 10b      1
 10b      2
 10b      3 
 10b      4 
 20b      1
 20b      2
 20b      3
 20b      4
```

Now I want to do randomization to reduce experimental errors like this

```
 Tem     Time
 10a      1
 10a      2
 10a      3 
 10a      4 
 20a      4 #( not the same sequence for Time in 10a)
 20a      2
 20a      3
 20a      1 
 #(for b, not same sequence for a in Tem)
 20b      3
 20b      1
 20b      2
 20b      4 
 10b      1 #(not the same sequence for Time in 20b)
 10b      3
 10b      2 
 10b      4
```

At the end, I need to randomize all the 12 samples together. 
I know it is very complicated. Could you help me to do this or give me some hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks! I am very new to R but I will try to understand the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Only randomize within `Tem`:

You can use `tidyverse` methods to randomly sample within groups (only you're sampling the whole dataset again):

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(Tem = c("a", "b", "c"), Time = rep(1:4, 3)) %>% arrange(Tem, Time)

df %>% group_by(Tem) %>% sample_frac(1)
# A tibble: 12 x 2
# Groups:   Tem [3]
      Tem  Time
   <fctr> <int>
 1      a     4
 2      a     1
 3      a     2
 4      a     3
 5      b     4
 6      b     2
 7      b     3
 8      b     1
 9      c     3
10      c     2
11      c     4
12      c     1
```

## If you want to randomize the `Tem` as well as `Time`

```
df %>% group_by(Tem) %>% sample_frac(1) %>% 
  split(df$Tem) %>% { .[sample(names(.), length(names(.)))] } %>%
  bind_rows()
# A tibble: 12 x 2
# Groups:   tem [3]
      tem  time
   <fctr> <int>
 1      c     2
 2      c     1
 3      c     4
 4      c     3
 5      b     4
 6      b     1
 7      b     2
 8      b     3
 9      a     1
10      a     2
11      a     4
12      a     3
```

(This one does the same within `Tem` sample as the first one, but then splits it into a list defined by `Tem` and re-samples the names, then binds it all back together. (This might not be the optimal solution.)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for!  As a beginner in R, I just want to thank you again!